# how do i test if i am connected to sql DB through vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have the following module and i would like to test connection. how do i test if the connection works? can you please be very specific with your answer:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Create a new SqlConnectionStringBuilder and
        ' initialize it with a few name/value pairs:
        Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(GetConnectionString())

        ' The input connection string used the 
        ' Server key, but the new connection string uses
        ' the well-known Data Source key instead.
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString)

        ' Pass the SqlConnectionStringBuilder an existing 
        ' connection string, and you can retrieve and
        ' modify any of the elements.
        builder.ConnectionString = _
            "server=http://sql.example.com;user id=******;" & _
            "password=***********;"
        ' Now that the connection string has been parsed,
        ' you can work with individual items.
        Console.WriteLine(builder.Password)
        builder.Password = "new@1Password"
        builder.AsynchronousProcessing = True

        ' You can refer to connection keys using strings, 
        ' as well. When you use this technique (the default
        ' Item property in Visual Basic, or the indexer in C#)
        ' you can specify any synonym for the connection string key
        ' name.
        builder("Server") = "."
        builder("Connect Timeout") = 1000

        ' The Item property is the default for the class, 
        ' and setting the Item property adds the value to the 
        ' dictionary, if necessary. 
        builder.Item("Trusted_Connection") = True
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString)

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to finish.")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetConnectionString() As String
        ' To avoid storing the connection string in your code,
        ' you can retrieve it from a configuration file. 
        Return "Server=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
          "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks"
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you have the connection string, you can open the connection using `Connection.Open()`. 
You can do that within a try-catch block to catch any errors that occur when you attempt to open the connection.enter code here

At any point before you close the connection with `Connection.Close()`, you can check its state using `Connection.State`. That returns values in an enum, such as `ConnectionState.Open`.

Comment: so, the mere act of opening a connection is verifying that you can connect to it

Answer (score 2):

create a connection object, and open it